# Too fuzzy text WPF on XP

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-xp

I have a problem: on xp in my WPF application text is too fuzzy, how can i fix this? On Windows 7 all ok!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this so-called "fuzzy text"?

Comment: You may want to look at this link http://windowsclient.net/wpf/white-papers/wpftextclarity.aspx

Comment: I think that this question is clear to anyone that is searching for an answer to this problem.  This question helped me find the answer that is given below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is WPF4 try to put: `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` attached properties to the window(s) 
 with text.